# running build.xml ant from another directory

Tags: xml, ant, junit

can we run ant build.xml outide our java workspave as an example another directory.cause I wanna put the whole java project in anoter directory and run the buildfile with ant somewhere else, please help, also is it possible to export the report also in one file in another directory?

Comment: Please describe your question in detail, e.g. examples of what you want, details of your "workspace", etc.

Answer (score 9):

Use the `buildfile` command line option, for example:

```
ant -buildfile pathetoanotherdirectory/build.xml
```